# How to refer to a field in a list to feed the function inside lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of df. My purpose is having one of the fields converted to another data type (date).

```
vista2018 <- data.frame(pr_code="001", pr_date="28/02/2018 00:00:00")
vista2019 <- data.frame(pr_code="002", pr_date="28/02/2019 00:00:00")
vista2020 <- data.frame(pr_code="003", pr_date="28/02/2020 00:00:00")
```

My way to work this out:

```
vistes <- list( vista2018, vista2019, vista2020)
vistes <- lapply(vistes, function(x) { 
  x$pr_date=as.Date(x$pr_date, format="%d/%m/%Y"); 
  return(x)}
);
```

Any guess on other more efficient or elegant solutions?

Comment: When you say field, do you mean a column in each of the data.frames?

Comment: Since, your solution seems to work, is there a specific reason why you want a more efficient or elegant solution? Phrased differently, what do you mean by efficient or elegant? For example, do you have a larger list of data.frames where your approach takes a long time?

Comment: You are right, I meant a column of the dataframe

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.